# How do I write a username and password to a record in a csv (txt) file through an account creation function that uses confirmation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I was wondering how I can write the users' input for 'account' and 'password_3' to a csv (txt) file as part of an account creation function. I am also trying to loop the function if 'password_4' does not have an input identical to 'password_3' or if any input has a length of 0. I would like both 'account' and 'password_3' to be written in the csv (txt) file as one new record. E.g:

```
account_1,password_1
account_2,password_2
etc......,etc.......
```

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def create_account():
    account = ""
    print "Create Account"
# Prompts user for input of account, password and password confirmation.
    account = raw_input("Enter login: ")
    password_3 = raw_input("Enter passsword: ")
    password_4 = raw_input("Confirm password: ")
# Sets the condition that if one input has a length of 0, the create_account function will loop.
    while len(account) == 0 or len(password_3) == 0 or len(password_4) == 0:
        create_account()
# Sets the condition that if the password input and password confirmation input do not match, the create_account function will loop.
    while password_3 != password_4:
        create_account()
# Sets the condition that if both of the coniditions set above are false, input will be stored and the loop will be broken.
    else:
        with open('User.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp,delimeter=',')
            data = [account,password_3]
            a.writerows(data)
## Writes input to the csv file for later use. Input is stored as one new record.
```

Sorry if this seems confusing or complicated. Please take into consideration that I am completely new to coding and Python. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently you are new to coding at all. Why 3 and 4 (suffixes in password_...)? I mean, why not password and repeated_password? Also, what do you exactly want to do? And what the hell are those while loops doing? I mean, what do you want them to do, because now they are mainly screwing this piece of code...

Comment: Could you please be clearer about what *you think* is wrong with the code you have written. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: It would probably be easier on you and a little bit clearer if you took all the `input`s out of your function and passed the info you needed as parameters, `def create_account(u_name, pw, confirm_pw)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your program should be like this:

```
def createAccount():
  account_name = raw_input('Enter login: ')
  password = enterPassword()
  appendAccount('User.csv', account_name, password)

def enterPassword():
  while True: # repeat forever
    password = raw_input('Enter password: ')
    password_again = raw_input('Confirm password: ')
    if len(password) < 5: # or whatever sanity check you might like
      print 'Your password is too short.'
    elif password != password_again:
      print 'Password and confirmation do not match.'
    else:
      return password
      # all is well; 'return' breaks the loop

def appendAccount(file_name, account_name, password):
   with open(file_name, 'a') as csv_file: # Note the 'a' mode for appending
      # use your writing logic, it seems fine
```

Try to avoid functions longer than 10 lines, and think hard to name them most appropriately. A function should do one clearly cut thing. I know, this feels silly the first few times, but then you come to appreciate how readable the program becomes.

Comment: Thank you, you've been most helpful! :)